Identify a movie about a slim woman which is heavy
I'd like to know the title of a movie I watched long time ago. These are what I remember:

I watched it in early 2000's
I think it's a Hollywood movie.
It's genre maybe a romance and comedy.
This is the plot of the movie. There's a man who attracted to a woman. The woman is slim, but it seems she is weighted far more than she looks. There's a scene of her breaking a chair when she sits.

I'll add more clues if I remember.

This sounds like Shallow Hal, starring Jack Black and Gwyneth Paltrow. This is a Romance / Comedy Hollywood movie from the early 2000's involving a heavy woman who looks slim, due to her inner beauty.

She only looks slim to him because he is hypnotized, because he judges people so superficially, to see their "inner" selves.

@AndrewMattson Hypnotized by Tony "Banana Hands" Robbins. Fun movie!
